# Unable to boot Windows 7 Home Premium Upgrade DVD from purchased media or USB thumb drive

Tags: windows-7, boot

I purchased the upgrade DVD for Windows 7 Home Premium in order to upgrade my Windows XP machine. I really want to do a clean install as my machine has been running XP for a long time and there is a lot of cruft that I don't want to carry along. When I attempt to boot from the DVD I get an "error code 5". I also have a Windows Vista SP1 DVD which boots just fine so I assume that there are no problems with my DVD drive (Sony DVD-RW drive) or my BIOS (VIA K8M800 running AMI BIOS 3.7 which is the latest). I have tried all different booting options to attempt to get the DVD to start the install.

I gave up on the DVD and tried to do the upgrade via a USB thumb drive by following the steps at http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/upgrade_03.asp. Every time I boot with USB drive in place I get a message stating that there is no boot record. The USB drive is a 8GB Sandisk Cruiser with the U3 stuff uninstalled.

If anyone can help with either the DVD or USB install it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

If you need more information just leave a comment and I'll add the information to this description when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the install from within Windows XP? Have a look here for some installation help:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7

Comment: This post appears to address your issue exactly:

http://www.unawave.de/windows-7-tipps/code5-error.html?lang=EN

Comment: I did not want to do the upgrade from within XP as I prefer to start from scratch with a clean harddrive. THANKS for that link. That is exactly what I was looking for. I have an older MSI motherboard so I will definitely have to try this all out this weekend. If it works then I'll let you know so you can move your comment to an answer that I'll accept.

Comment: Sounds good, keep us posted.

Comment: joeqwerty, so far the install that you linked to in your comment is working. I'll add another comment when it is done then I would request that you move your comment to an actual answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Since these comments are attached to my original answer, how about just accepting it?

Comment: Finished the install. The reason is that your answer didn't help me but the link in your comment did. I'll leave it up to you. I just want that you get credit for finding the answer and also for anyone else having the same problem to be able to find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but I don't think you can do what you're trying to do with a DVD Upgrade for Windows Home Premium. I'm pretty sure you need to buy the full blown version of Windows 7 and do a complete install.

Comment: There's no upgrade path from XP to 7 but there is upgrade pricing and an upgrade DVD. When performing the install you need to select Custom install after booting the DVD, which will perform a clean install. The problem here is that the DVD appears to not be bootable.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I did an upgrade from XP to Vista, setup offerred to do a clean install. It just dumped my old system (all the current files on C:) into a folder. You can just delete the folder later. Does 7 not have such an option?

Comment: To me that is not a clean install. That is an in place upgrade where it takes the stuff that it is not going to use and places it in an "old" directory. I tried that and it worked just fine but I want to do a "clean" install on a newly formatted hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, you can do an upgrade from XP to Win 7 using an upgrade DVD and doing this by wiping XP off the machine. I have written about this on my blog whih referenced sources to other sites as well [here](http://blog.tbits.ie/2009/11/get-weven-upg/).

As for the USB to boot you need UNetBootWin which can be found [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make the USB bootable, in order for it to work you need to make an ISO copy of the DVD and let UNetBootWin take care of making your USB stick bootable.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thanks Tom but I've already read the stuff at Paul T.'s website (aka the link in the description). This even steps through the USB boot option although it uses different programs. I will check those out if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to prepare your USB Pen Drive with **[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)**?

Comment: I have not but I will look into it